# How to set different selection colors for the different cells in a QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets

I'd like to have the different selection colors for the different cells of the QTableWidget.

To change selection color for the whole table, I can use:

```cpp
QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget;
table->setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item{selection-background-color:#ff0000;}");
```

To set the usual background color of the single cells, it's possible to write in the following way:

```cpp
table->setItem(row, column, new QTableWidgetItem(""));
table->item(row, column)->setBackgroundColor(QColor(255,255,0));
```

But I couldn't find any info about the different selection colors for the different cells.

Answer (score 0):

I used a delegate to resolve this issue:

```cpp
class MyDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
  public:
    MyDelegate( QObject *parent ) : QItemDelegate( parent ) { }
    void paint( QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const;

};

void MyDelegate::paint( QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index ) const
{
     QItemDelegate::paint( painter, option, index );
    
     QColor background = QColor(rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);
     QColor background2 = QColor(255, 255, 255);

     painter->fillRect(option.rect, background);

     if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
         painter->fillRect(option.rect, background);
     } else {
         painter->fillRect(option.rect, background2);
     }
}
```

How will it work? With each selection, it will generate a new color for the selected item.

Delegate integration:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    QTableWidget* m_pTableWidget = new QTableWidget();
    m_pTableWidget->setRowCount(10);
    m_pTableWidget->setColumnCount(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_pTableWidget->rowCount(); ++i) {
        m_pTableWidget->setItemDelegateForRow(i, new MyDelegate(m_pTableWidget));

    }
    m_pTableWidget->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

You can change the code and give a specific color for certain item.