# Selection color for QTableWidget cell is different if custom cellwidget is used

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets, qpalette

I wrote a custom table widget which is derived from `QTableWidget`. The last two columns in this widget use a custom cell widget (one containing a `QCheckBox`, the other a `QLineEdit`, with some optional `QPushButtons`).

Now, I added the option to color the table widget rows in a darker blue or orange color, depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

The code for this basically looks like the following:

```cpp
// Color the standard tablewidget cells
for (auto j = 0; j < FIRST_FOUR_COLUMNS; j++) {
    tableWidget->item(i, j)->setBackground(isCheckedColor);
}

QPalette palette;
palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, isCheckedColor);
// For the push buttons
palette.setColor(QPalette::Button, buttonColor);

// Now color the cell widgets
tableWidget->cellWidget(i, COL_CHECKBOX)->setAutoFillBackground(true);
tableWidget->cellWidget(i, COL_LINE_EDIT)->setAutoFillBackground(true);
tableWidget->cellWidget(i, COL_CHECKBOX)->setPalette(palette);
tableWidget->cellWidget(i, COL_LINE_EDIT)->setPalette(palette);
```

It works fine. However, the following occurs if a row is now selected:

[image: Orange row]

[image: Blue row]

The upper image shows a selected orange row, while the lower image shows a selected blue row. As you might see, the highlighting color for the last two columns is different compared to the other, standard table widget cells.

However, I want all of it to look the same.

What I tried so far was:

- Changing the background color via a custom stylesheet (for example):
  `tableWidget->setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item{ selection-background-color:#ff0000; }");`
- subclassing `QItemDelegate` and overriding the `paint`-method to display my own colors.

Alternatives were discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178983/qtablewidget-different-selection-colors-for-the-different-cells).

But none of that worked so far, still the same problems.

How do I solve this problem?

A minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QWidget>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Setup widgets
    auto* const tableWidget = new QTableWidget(1, 2);
    tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem());
    auto *const cellWidget = new QWidget;
    tableWidget->setCellWidget(0, 1, cellWidget);

    // Apply palette color
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, QColor(255, 194, 10, 60));
    tableWidget->item(0, 0)->setBackground(palette.color(QPalette::Base));
    tableWidget->cellWidget(0, 1)->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    tableWidget->cellWidget(0, 1)->setPalette(palette);

    // Layout and main window
    auto* const mainWindow = new QMainWindow;
    auto* const layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(tableWidget);
    mainWindow->setCentralWidget(tableWidget);
    mainWindow->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

project(ExampleProject LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(ExampleProject
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(ExampleProject
    PRIVATE Qt::Widgets
)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using QCheckBoxes (instead of the standard check state) and QLineEdits (instead of opening persistent editors)?

Comment: @musicamante Yes there are specific reasons for these widgets as they are used combined with other widgets inside the columns.

Comment: **Just an observation:** the difference to me seems because the cell widget gets drawn after the highlight rect is drawn. If you use a fully opaque color (remove the alpha channel from your color), the widget will not look highlighted at all. So, perhaps the only way is to custom paint the highlight color for the cell widgets as well. I could be wrong, but this might help you get close to a solution.

Comment: @Bakefish Combined *how*? You say that there are reasons, but you are not explaining them. Most of the times, cell widgets are used for the wrong reasons, while proper delegates should be used instead; this seems a typical example, as: 1. the item's (or model's) check state can be used instead of a QCheckBox; 2. QLineEdit is the standard editor for any string content. In the former case, there'd be no style issue at all; in the latter, it's just a matter of properly setting editor's properties within `createEditor()`. A view's QSS `::item` selector has absolutely **NO** effect on cell widgets.

Comment: @A.R.M I tried this one out... unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: @musicamante 
I tried using the checkState method before, but the checkboxes are not centered then. To address this problem, the least complex solutions I found so far were focusing on using a QCheckBox for a cellwidget instead. 
For the QLineEdit, it's not just the line edit itself, but also additional custom QPushButtons which are displayed along with the line edit in a widget.
You are suggesting to place everything in custom item delegates, do I understand that correctly? Might try this out, would be glad if it worked. However, it wouldn't solve the problem itself.

Comment: @Bakefish It's generally better to use delegates, as it makes interaction with the model much more robust and reliable. In any case, the issue you have is that you're using `setAutoFillBackground(true)` which makes the "index widget" draw *over* the background, and since you're using a partially transparent color, the alpha values are blended (see the [Alpha-Blended Drawing](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#alpha-blended-drawing) section of QColor docs). You should also avoid mixing QPalette with style sheets (the docs [warn about this](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#palette-prop)).

Comment: @musicamante You were absolutely right, the alpha value and auto filling were responsible for this problem. I found a solution, at least for this problem (fortunately, I did not use style sheets beforehand). But nevertheless... this needs some refactoring, so I will switch to delegates in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (or more of a workaround):
As pointed out in the comments, the problem is caused by the cell widget's alpha values. Since this value is not the maximum alpha value, the row selection and cell widget's background color are blended, creating a different highlighting color compared to the other columns.
A first, quick solution is to set the alpha value for the cell widgets to 0 so that the blending is prevented:

```
connect(tableWidget, &QTableWidget::itemSelectionChanged, this, [tableWidget] {
    const auto selectedRows = tableWidget->selectionModel()->selectedRows();

    for (const auto& selectedModel : selectedRows) {
        const auto row = selectedModel.row();

        auto palette = tableWidget->cellWidget(row, COL_CELL_WIDGET)->palette();
        auto color = palette.color(QPalette::Base);
        color.setAlpha(0);
        palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, color);

        tableWidget->cellWidget(row, COL_CELL_WIDGET)->setPalette(palette);
    }
});
```

Keep in mind however, that once the item selection changes again or items are unselected, the color values for the rows which were selected before need to be changed to their old values.